# ensure hidden field is not exposing vulnerability in nodejs

Tags: node.js, security, xss

I have this hidden form field which rendered from nodejs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="currentUrl" value={currentUrl} />
```

This field is for when javascript is disabled and I need to know which page to return to after a form has been posted.

I am using [csruf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf) to try and mitigate any problems.

How can I guard against hackers abusing the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be concerned about open redirection in this case, and that's not a client-side problem. When you send this form to your server, it will redirect to the url provided if I understand correctly. You need to make sure (on the server) that the url points to your application (or an allowed other domain), before redirecting to it. It is a vulnerability if a user can send an arbitrary url where he then gets redirected. One way to validate the url would be to process it with [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_strings_and_url_objects) and check the host.

Also XSS might be an issue, but I think that should already be mitigated by the template engine that writes `{currentUrl}`.